# how use CSP with pdf.js? I have a problem with worker

Tags: javascript, pdf, content-security-policy, pdf.js

MVC c# application.
I'm using CSP, with this format:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js;
    style-src  'self' https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css;
    object-src 'self';
    base-uri 'self';
    connect-src 'self';
    font-src 'self';
    frame-src 'self';
    img-src 'self';
    manifest-src 'self';
    media-src 'self';
    worker-src blob:;"/>
```

In the proyect, i use **pdf.js** for base64 pdfs. I see my documents, but I dont see the buttons bar from pdf.js.
My browser console shows:
[image]

and my javascript function use:

```
var DivContenedorPDF = document.createElement("div");
DivContenedorPDF.id = "pdf-viewer";
var pdfData = atob(b64);
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';....
```

I tried add blob: in default-src, using local pdf.js (this has not errors but not work)...

extra info:

- api.js is part of pdf.js webpack.
- My test are in pre-production (in localhost,console throws 0 errors).
- I dont have CSS for pdf.js buttons bar.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@granty gave me the answer: the message in console isn't generic. I don't know why, but my IIS used another CSP configuration.
My code works deleting the configuration in response header section of IIS.

Comment: Power move making your answer based on another answer and marking it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Try adding blob: to script-src.

Comment: still not works with the same message error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser console shown CSP:

```
default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' *.google.com
```

that differs you shown in the meta-tag:

```
default-src 'self'; ...
```

Looks like in fact you does issue Content-Security-Policy elsewhere than you think (and edit).

*worker-src blob:* in the meta-tag is [totally enough](https://csplite.com/csp/test236/#test) to allow worker creation from blob-URL.

Comment: hello @granty. The console uses a generic message in the error. I declare once in all my code.

Comment: Console warnings always based on real CSP. Policy blockquoted in the console warning somehow ends up in the browser. Pls check on duplicates `<meta csp>` in the HTML code, and check in the developer tools of browser that page haven't CSP HTTP-header